# In SAS How do I iterate two dates and then insert them to a sql statements as an outer loop?

Tags: loops, macros, sas

I want the outer loop to iterate the dates.
The inner loop goes through different locations and then as the loop for location ends and then the date loop to iterate.  The inner loop for location works fine.

I would like for the line that the where statement is to say

"where t1.Date BETWEEN 'date' and 'date1' "  How do I go about creating that macro? Date and date1 must iterate at the same time in order to be two days away from each other at all times.

```
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Report_dates&i AS /* every time the date changes/newtable*/
SELECT t1.ReportsID,
          t1.Type,
          t1.buys,
          t1.sells,
          t1.Age
          FROM work.candy as t1    
where (t1.Date BETWEEN '14Feb2016:0:0:0'dt AND '16Feb2016:0:0:0'dt) AND 
           (t1.Location = "SouthFlorida");
QUIT;


data list_of_dates;
format date date9.;
do Date = '01JUL2016'd to today();
output;
end;
run;

data list_of_dates1;
format date date9.;
do Date1 = '02JUL2016'd to today();
output;
end;
run;
```

The two loops work seperately when tested. But when put together I keep getting a sas error along the lines of " The quoted string currently being processed has become more than 262 characters long.  You might have unbalanced quotation marks. But I don't there are any unbalanced quotation marks, like I said they work separately when tested but not together.

```
%macro queryLoop(startDate=, i=);

%macro loop(listA, listB);

%let p = %sysfunc(countw(&FACLNBR, %str( )));
%do i=1 %to &p;
    %let lista = %scan(&olista, &i, %str( ));
    %let listb = %scan(&olistb, &i, %str( ));


PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Report_dates&i AS /* every time the date changes/newtable*/
SELECT t1.ReportsID,
          t1.Type,
          t1.buys,
          t1.sells,
          t1.Age
          FROM work.candy as t1    
where (datepart(t1.Date) BETWEEN &startDate AND &startDate+2 ) AND 
           (t1.Location = &list);
QUIT;

%end;
%mend; 

%loop(listA_1 listA_2, listB_1 listB_2);

%mend queryLoop;

data list_of_dates;
i=1;
format date date9.;
do Date = '01NOV2015'd to '01JAN2016'd;
string = catt('%queryLoop(startDate=', date, ', i=', i, ');');
call execute(string);
i+1;
output;
end;
run;

;*';*";*/;quit;run;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. But if you require that DATE1 be two days after DATE then just make it so. `date1=date+2;`

Comment: Why are you creating dates when you have datetime variables?

Comment: Because your query has no aggregations, I suspect a data set with a do loop and output statement would achieve the same results. Essentially you're grouping your data into three day intervals and each record needs to be in the interval. Not sure why you're doing this and if something like a Multilabel format or a SQL query directly wouldn't solve this issue in a more efficient manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, based on your previous question, this question and an educated guess. You need to first wrap the query in a macro and then when creating your dates, you can pass the call the macro with those dates directly using Call Execute.

See the code below. Note that I've commente out the call execute because I can't run the code, obviously.

```
%macro queryLoop(startDate=, i=);
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE WORK.Report_dates&i AS /* every time the date changes/newtable*/
SELECT t1.ReportsID,
          t1.Type,
          t1.buys,
          t1.sells,
          t1.Age
          FROM work.candy as t1    
where (datepart(t1.Date) BETWEEN &startDate AND &startDate+2 ) AND 
           (t1.Location = "SouthFlorida");
QUIT;
%mend queryLoop;

data list_of_dates;
i=1;
format date date9.;
do Date = '01JUL2016'd to today();
string = catt('%queryLoop(startDate', date, ', i=', i, ');');
*call execute(string);
I+1;
output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: it seems that what is getting passed into start date is the numbers in the third column string so startDate = 20636  http://imgur.com/a/ao6sL the database doesn't recognize that format. How do I pass in the  date format from the second column.

Comment: Did you run it? That's how SAS stores dates so changing the format only changes the appearance but doesn't affect the actual data.

Comment: you are right that does work, the error keeps hopping around. I posted below my main question more on the errors I am getting. Should I post a new question or just append on here as I did?

Comment: I don't know TBH. Re your question, run your macro with the MPRINT and SYMBOLGEN options on so you can see what code is being passed to SAS. `options mprint symbolgen;`  You can post on communities.sas.com for a less restrictive forum.